# How to specify a target BUILD file

Tags: bazel

I am trying to build/install the dependencies of a project called `envoy`.

The project directory looks like this:

```
$ ls -salt
total 176
 0 drwxr-xr-x.  3 app app    37 Aug 31 13:06 ..
 4 drwxrwxr-x. 16 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 .
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  2 app app    23 Aug  4 02:28 .circleci
 4 -rwxrwxr-x.  1 app app   259 Aug  4 02:28 .clang-format
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  2 app app    22 Aug  4 02:28 .github
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app   217 Aug  4 02:28 .gitignore
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app    61 Aug  4 02:28 BUILD
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app   433 Aug  4 02:28 CODEOWNERS
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app   139 Aug  4 02:28 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
12 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app 10993 Aug  4 02:28 CONTRIBUTING.md
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  1421 Aug  4 02:28 DCO
 8 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  4221 Aug  4 02:28 DEPRECATED.md
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  2189 Aug  4 02:28 DEVELOPER.md
12 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  8202 Aug  4 02:28 GOVERNANCE.md
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  1718 Aug  4 02:28 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
12 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app 11358 Aug  4 02:28 LICENSE
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app   108 Aug  4 02:28 NOTICE
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  2923 Aug  4 02:28 OWNERS.md
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  2211 Aug  4 02:28 PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
 8 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  4844 Aug  4 02:28 README.md
 8 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app  6907 Aug  4 02:28 REPO_LAYOUT.md
16 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app 13200 Aug  4 02:28 SECURITY_RELEASE_PROCESS.md
12 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app 12085 Aug  4 02:28 STYLE.md
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app     6 Aug  4 02:28 VERSION
 4 -rw-rw-r--.  1 app app   514 Aug  4 02:28 WORKSPACE
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  9 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 api
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  3 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 bazel
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  4 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 ci
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  4 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 configs
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  3 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 docs
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  8 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 examples
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  3 app app    18 Aug  4 02:28 include
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  2 app app    41 Aug  4 02:28 restarter
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  7 app app    70 Aug  4 02:28 source
 0 drwxrwxr-x.  3 app app    50 Aug  4 02:28 support
 4 drwxrwxr-x. 15 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 test
 4 drwxrwxr-x.  6 app app  4096 Aug  4 02:28 tools
```

There are two bazel `WORKSPACE` files:

```
$ find . -iname WORKSPACE
./WORKSPACE 
./ci/WORKSPACE
```

I guess I have to build the bazel native dependencies from the top directory, but i do not know how to specify the target BUILD file. Could you please advise on the `bazel build` 
 command to achieve that ?

**EDIT:** am trying to build what is mentioned in step#2 over here https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/bazel/README.md

**EDIT #2:** when doing `$ bazel build //source/exe:envoy`

i get the following error

```
WARNING: /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/BUILD:1972:1: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule @com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc_nanopb: please do not import '@com_github_grpc_grpc//third_party/nanopb:pb_common.c' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there. Since this rule was created by the macro 'grpc_generate_one_off_targets', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl:172:12
WARNING: /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/BUILD:1972:1: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule @com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc_nanopb: please do not import '@com_github_grpc_grpc//third_party/nanopb:pb_decode.c' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there. Since this rule was created by the macro 'grpc_generate_one_off_targets', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl:172:12
WARNING: /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/BUILD:1972:1: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule @com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc_nanopb: please do not import '@com_github_grpc_grpc//third_party/nanopb:pb_encode.c' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there. Since this rule was created by the macro 'grpc_generate_one_off_targets', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl:172:12
ERROR: /home/app/.cache/bazel/_bazel_app/93cf2aaa5a193ee1dca34ebc2235b4f8/external/io_bazel_rules_go/proto/BUILD.bazel:21:1: no such package '@org_golang_x_net//context': failed to fetch org_golang_x_net: 2018/09/12 03:10:46 unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/net"
 and referenced by '@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:go_grpc'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//source/exe:envoy' failed; build aborted: no such package '@org_golang_x_net//context': failed to fetch org_golang_x_net: 2018/09/12 03:10:46 unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/net"
INFO: Elapsed time: 73.577s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (253 packages loaded)
```

Could you please advise further ?

**EDIT #3:** For reasons of completeness, I run this under `scl` so that i have a more recent GCC version

```
- name: "Install envoy dependencies"
        yum: name="{{ item }}" state=latest
        with_items:
          - cmake
          - libtool
          - libstdc++
          - bazel
          - centos-release-scl
          - devtoolset-7-gcc-c++   # scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
        environment:
          http_proxy: "{{ prx.http }}"
          https_proxy: "{{ prx.https }}"
```

meaning that I enter a shell by typing `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` and then the usual stuff

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build?

Comment: thanks @Jin for looking into it, see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

From [DEVELOPER.md](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md), to build Envoy:

```
$ bazel build //source/exe:envoy
```

This `//source/exe:envoy` target is defined in [`source/exe/BUILD`](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/00ffe44a2951321e8a1ad2e54fd4e014c059f70c/source/exe/BUILD#L18).

To run all tests:

```
$ bazel test //test/...
```

`...` refers to all targets, recursively.

To run a specific tests, e.g. `async_client_impl_test` defined in [`test/common/http/BUILD`](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/00ffe44a2951321e8a1ad2e54fd4e014c059f70c/test/common/http/BUILD#L15). `//test/common/http` is the package name.

```
$ bazel test //test/common/http:async_client_impl_test
```

You can run these commands from anywhere in the project directory because of `//` in the absolute target labels.

Comment: hi @Jin thanks for the hint, but that is about building envoy itself, and not its dependecies. there are 2 steps before that (3rd part dependencies and bazel dependencies), hence the question is about those 2 steps.

Comment: You should not need to build them directly. Bazel understands that Envoy or its tests depend on the Bazel native deps, so when you build Envoy itself, the deps will be built before Envoy automatically.

Comment: If you want to build a target from a Bazel native external dep explicitly, specify the target label syntax: `@<repository name>//package/name:target`.

Comment: please see EDIT#2, according to documentation i shouldn't build every target independently, right ? please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What version of Bazel are you using, and which commit of Envoy are you building on? I just built Envoy master with Bazel 0.16.0.

Comment: And yes, you do not need to build the dependencies manually. Have you installed Go?

Comment: go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64, Build label: 0.16.1- (@non-git), gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)

Comment: envoy: commit 7707c3ba095da6c4bd55afb4a064907443792c7c
Author: tianqian.zyf <445188383@qq.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 6 11:50:12 2018 +0800

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort you are putting into this, the issue is still there, which distribution do you use, Centos ?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux. I’m not sure if Envoy has been tested to build on RH.

Comment: I think you might have better answers filing an issue on Envoy: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues

Answer (score 0):

Can you try "go get -u google.golang.org/grpc" and see if it works?

Comment: yes, that works `$ go get -u -v google.golang.org/grpc
Fetching https://google.golang.org/grpc?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://google.golang.org/grpc?go-get=1 (status code 200) ...`

Comment: i added more info on EDIT#2 about the error messages before it fails

Comment: So the unrecognized path changed from grpc to golang.org/x/net after you manually go get the grpc package?

Comment: thanks @lyuxuan for looking into it, but am not following you :) could you please elaborate on it further please ?

Comment: Before you net EDIT, I remember the error message says `unrecognized import path "google.golang.org/grpc"`. And after the EDIT, it says `unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/net"`. That's what I meant in my previous comment, asking whether `go get -u google.golang.org/grpc` changed the error message.